# How do I set a document property (such as document.webkitFullscreenElement) to null?

Tags: javascript, html

When the fullscreen button of a html5 video tag is clicked in an Android WebView, document.webkitFullscreenElement is set to the video that i clicked on (according to the print out of it). Is there a way I can manually set this to null?

before i hit fullscreen on the video

```
console.log(document.webkitFullscreenElement); //null
```

after I hit fullscreen on the video

```
console.log(document.webkitFullscreenElement); //[object HTMLVideoElement]
```

set to null

```
document.webkitFullscreenElement = null;
```

after set to null

```
console.log(document.webkitFullscreenElement); //[object HTMLVideoElement]
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s not an editable property, but you could create your own feature detection variable:

`var hasFullscreenEl = !!document.webkitFullscreenElement;`

Then you could set it to `null` later. Not exactly sure what the use case is here, so let me know if this isn’t helpful.

Comment: That's helpful but the solution won't work for me. I am using document.webkitFullscreenElement to detect if the fullscreen video button was tapped/clicked on. If document.webkitFullscreenElement can't be reset to null, I have no way to know if the user tapped on the fullscreen button more than once because on the first time it is tapped the button is set to some object, then it never gets set back to null because I am not actually putting the video in fullscreen with that button (I am, but by using an Android VideoView instead of the html5/javascript so it doesnt get reset :/ ).

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand now. I’ve never tried to do that before but perhaps this article will help http://www.intheloftstudios.com/blog/detecting-html5-video-fullscreen-and-events

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. I just need to manually call this.

```
document.webkitExitFullscreen();
```